# Orbitals involved in Ni(CO)₄

Tags: orbitals, molecular-orbital-theory, magnetism

Which orbitals are filled? Is it diamagnetic? According to CFT, $\ce{CO}$ is a strong field ligand, so will it pair the electrons and be diamagnetic?

Comment: I can't understand this answer(http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7883/how-do-i-determine-crystal-field-splitting-for-example-for-nico4). It says d10 while nickel has 8 d electrons.

Comment: It is because $4s$ electrons of $\ce{Ni}$ atom are "pushed" into $3d$ orbitals in the strong field of $\ce{CO}$ ligands. See, for example, [here](http://www.adichemistry.com/jee/qb/coordination-chemistry/1/q1.html) for details.

Comment: So, yes, you are perfectly right. The strong field of $\ce{CO}$ ligands will "push" and "pair up" the $\ce{Ni}$ electrons in $3d$ orbitals and $\ce{Ni(CO)4}$ is indeed diamagnetic.

Comment: But that push will be against aufbau principle @Wildcat

Comment: Yes, it does. And it is a well-known "breakage" of the Aufbau principle similar to what happens in the transition metals cations. See, for instance, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration#Shortcomings_of_the_Aufbau_principle).